# cvs command on Ubuntu 11.10 seems broken?

Tags: linux, cvs

I have a clean install of Ubuntu 11.10 on my laptop.  I installed CVS with the command "`sudo apt-get install cvs`".  I have never had any trouble with the CVS command before, but in this case, I get this:

```
$ cvs
cvs checkout: No CVSROOT specified!  Please use the `-d' option
cvs [checkout aborted]: or set the CVSROOT environment variable.
```

The real puzzle to me is why it is assuming the "checkout" command.  That doesn't happen in other installations, where it just gives a usage message.  But, OK, there is no CVSROOT defined, so if I define one, say like this:

```
$ export CVSROOT=:pserver:me@abc.com:/cvsroot
```

I then get another very strange message, which again indicates that it is assuming "checkout":

```
$ cvs
co: invalid option -- 'z'
Usage:
  cvs checkout [-ANPRcflnps] [-r rev] [-D date] [-d dir]
  [-j rev1] [-j rev2] [-k kopt] modules...
```

This isn't just with the plain "cvs" command, by the way - `cvs login`, `cvs checkout`, `cvs update` and `cvs someGobbledegook` all give the same result.

Any ideas what to try next?

Comment: Ubuntu 10.11 doesn't exist. Do you mean 10.10 or 11.10? The pattern is "release year.release month"

Comment: Also, you have 2 "export" bits on 1 line. That doesn't look right.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what do you get if you type `alias cvs`?

Comment: My best guess is that you have an alias or function named `cvs`.  What does `type -a cvs` print?

Comment: Check that 'cvs' isn't aliased by your shell. That alias may be misconstructed or trying to pass a -z option

Comment: `type -a cvs` gives `cvs is /usr/bin/cvs`
`alias cvs` gives ``bash: alias: cvs: not found`

Comment: @user1116805 Can you give the output of `which cvs`, `ls -l $(which cvs)`, and `file $(which cvs)`? That's my usual set of steps to check that I'm executing the command I think I'm executing, and that it's not a shell script wrapper or symlink to something else. If it turns out to be a shell script, then look inside it. Also, check to see if you have a `~/.cvsrc` file, and if so, add the contents of it to your question. I have checked that a `sudo apt-get install cvs` works just fine on my copy of Ubuntu 11.10, so there's likely something odd about your environment.

Comment: @user1116805 Just want to check to see if you have tried the advice I gave. Any progress on getting cvs to work, or taking a more detailed look at what you're actually using?

Answer (score 1):

1) CVS should be installable and should work fine on any version of Ubuntu (and Debian, and Fedora, etc etc)

2) Your "export" syntax (at least what you posted) is incorrect:

```
# BAD
export CVSROOT=export CVSROOT=:pserver:me@abc.com:/cvsroot

# BETTER
export CVSROOT=:pserver:me@abc.com:/cvsroot
```

3) Make sure /cvsroot exists and has appropriate permissions.

Since you're using pserver (not really a good idea, but...) make sure user "me.abc.com" is defined in your /cvsroot/passwd file

4) Make sure the "cvs" command isn't aliased

5) Make sure the pserver service is configured, enabled and running (again, pserver isn't necessarily a good idea)

6) This link is probably still applicable to your version of Ubuntu:

https://help.ubuntu.com/10.04/serverguide/C/cvs-server.html

ADDENDUM:
7) Check your firewall (port 2401)

8) Take a Wireshark trace: see if there's any attempted connections

Comment: Only point 4 is potentially relevant to the problem the OP is asking about.

Comment: As Keith Thompson says, most of this isn't relevant.  I am not trying to set up a CVS server, just connect to an existing one; and the problem is not that I have subtle issues connecting to it, but that, with or without a CVSROOT set up, I see this weird behavior of jumping straight into the "co" sub-command, regardless of what actual command I give it.

Comment: @user1116805 - Check your firewall, too :)

Comment: I'm grateful for your suggestions, but again I can't see how a blocked firewall port could be relevant. It is going straight to the "co" subcommand, whether there is a CVSROOT or not.

Comment: @user1116805: And if you type `/bin/cvs` (again, with no arguments), you get the same result, yes?  What does `ls -l /bin/cvs` tell you?